# Get Location of Particle Keys with real unit size

Tags: python, scripting, particles, hair, units

I get my location of all particles with this script.

```
ps = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].particle_systems["ParticleSystem"]
ps.particles[0].hair_keys[5].co
-> Vector((0.4008302092552185, -0.8442497253417969, 1.4897942543029785))
```

The location is not in Unit Scale centimeter 0.01. How can I use and calculate the unit scale?

Answer (score 1):

With a function like this one:

```
def get_unitscale(scene):
    unit_settings = scene.unit_settings

    if unit_settings.system in {"METRIC", "IMPERIAL"}:
        # The units used in modelling are for display only. 
        # Behind the scenes everything is in meters.
        return unit_settings.scale_length
    else:
        # No unit system in use
        return 1
```

By multiplying with the scale value, you get coordinates in meters:

```
scale = get_unitscale(bpy.context.scene)
co = ps.particles[0].hair_keys[5].co
# Assuming the unit system is set to meters
co_in_meters = co * scale
```

By the way, there is also the `co_hair()` method for getting hair coordinates:
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html?highlight=co_hair#bpy.types.ParticleSystem.co_hair

And if you want to retrieve coordinates of the hair with final render settings, you will have to call `set_resolution()` first:
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html?highlight=co_hair#bpy.types.ParticleSystem.set_resolution

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have exported an FBX in 20cm x 20cm. I exported the particles as apx. Unfortunately, the particles are 100x smaller than the fbx. Then I noticed that the direction is wrong. I have adjusted my export settings in blender for UE4. Forward: X Forward. Up: Z Up. How can I include them in that direction? But first, only the scale is important to me.

Comment: The unit value 0.1 seems to have the right size, but 0.01 is set for centimeters, but that's too small.